# Administrative Login Permissions Disabled

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, administrator, permissions

Another Super User disabled login permissions for every group, including Super User; no one can login.

Is there a straight forward way to reverse this from within the database?

P.S.

If anyone can spot anything abnormal in my _assets table, that'd be amazing.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TxXT2L2o5pF1LI-qVvlr6h9yL8DvU6orOYihJLztoFU/edit?usp=sharing

To clarify what's happening functionally:

- Navigate to /administrator
- Insert credentials.
- Hit login.
- Nothing happens.
- No messages, errors, or warnings. (Including JS console.)
- Putting in invalid credentails will display an error per the usuall.
- Putting in correct credentials simply does nothing.

Comment: Can you share more information on what he did? I don't think it's possible to remove user-users permissions, or at least it's very difficult to do so.

Comment: @FFrewin I quote, "i just turned off ability to log in in the permissions". Unfortunetely that's all I have for now. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like the issue lies inside your assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still hard to believe how this user was able to remove Super Users permissions - it really takes some efforts to achieve this. Again are you sure this is the case ? Are you getting any special message when trying to login?

It can be just that he disabled some plugins.

I would suggest first to check with PHPmyAdmin in the extensions table to see if the following plugins are enabled :

> plg_user_joomla
>
> plg_authentication_joomla

If they are not enabled, their value will be '0', so re-enable these plugins by changing the value to '1' (no quotes).

If this is not the case, and you are sure the issue comes from the core permissions that have been changed in the global configuration, you could try run the following sql query within PHPmyAdmin.

```
update `jos_assets` set `rules` = '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1,"7":1},"core.login.offline":{"6":1},"core.admin":{"8":1,"10":1},"core.manage":{"7":1},"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},"core.delete":{"6":1},"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}'
where `name` = 'root.1';
```

This will revert the default core permissions for the core usergroups.
In the case that you have the core usergroups but have custom core permissions, the above code will also change this and after a possible successful login, you will have to re-do your custom permissions.

Note that it won't work if you have changed and created custom usergroups. In this scenario, let us know so we can work it from that point.

In any case, backup your current database before doing anything manually in there.

Comment: just saw that you have posted your assets table. I will check it.

Comment: Nice call, plg_user_joomla was disabled. Thank you tons.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla stores all the access permission rules in #__assets table.

There is a field rules in #__assets table which contains permission value, so you need to update the table with your values.

I have not done such changes directly in database before so don't know what exactly you need to put as default value.

Refer [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_14) for understanding access permissions.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is more that the "last" SuperUser is unknown. It shouldn't be possible to deactivate/delete that one. Don't want to test it right now. The SuperUser has hardcoded permissions.

You can check this

'#__usergroups' : id 8 exists

'#__user_usergroup_map' : at least one group_id 8 should exist

'#__users' : find the user to log in with.

If you don't know the password, I hope you know how to fix the above table entries.

Now it should be possible to correct the missing permissions the "normal" backend way

Hope this works.

Comment: I've got all of the above, everything looks good in those tables. I know the passwords, it simply does not allow me to log in, no errors. Thanks.